# Jmeter- Unable to understand result for the workflow

Tags: jmeter

My website workflow is as follows:

User Name-->Password-->Click on login button-->Click on Report menu(Daily Transaction)--->Select date and device in report-->Click on Generate button.

Now I want to check load testing for this scenario that if multiple users gets logged in and access the reports, how my website will act?

I have created csv file for multiple user login with report data. But not able to understand the output coming. It is displaying Login request twice i.e. Login request and under daily report request it is again displaying login request. I have created Login request and report request separately.

In result I am not getting why it is displaying login request again under daily report request.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is due to 1st login request failure as daily report request is not available for non-authenticated user. I would recommend taking the following steps to resolve your issue:

1. Add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan. It will automatically care about handling cookies and hopefully will be enough to let you to proceed.
2. If not - record your login request several times and inspect recorded requests to see if there are any differences. If they are - you'll need to provide some mandatory dynamic parameter along with credentials. In that case test Scenario skeleton will look as follows:

   - GET request to Login Page

     - Extract dynamic parameter value
   - POST request to Login Page providing username, password and dynamic parameter name/value pair

See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide for more details on dynamic parameters extraction and usage bits, even if your application is not ASP.NET based it should still give you a clue on what needs to be done.

Comment: Thx Dmitri... I have added Cookies and caches too under my test plan along with clear option per iternation. Actually, i have added http requests manually instead of recording it. Now i have recorded my workflow like Login-->access daily report, it is displaying result as login-->navigate to home page-->access daily report.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Transaction Controllers this can yield misleading results like you are seeing.

For example, take the following:

- Transaction Controller - Name "Login"

  - HTTP Sample - Name "Login"

If "Generate Parent Sample" is selected on the transaction controller, you will only see the Transaction Controller in your results.  If this option is not selected, you will see both the HTTP Sample AND the Transaction Controller in the result set.

Also, please note that the "Parent Sample" time is recorded as the TOTAL time taken to do all requests in the transaction end to end!!  In almost all cases this reports inaccurate times because a real web environment has asynchronous calls.

For this reason it is strongly encouraged to avoid transaction controllers.  In one case you report end-to-end time for all samples which is incorrect, and the other alternative is to report the transaction controller AND the sub-samples, which in turn makes your test report the incorrect rate of transactions.